# Does DB2 implement multi-table indexes?

Tags: sql, indexing, db2, query-performance, multi-table

I'm afraid this functionality may not exist [yet]. I wanted to use an index that spans multiple tables in DB2. I know Oracle and SQL server implement them (with more or less options) and that PostreSQL doesn't seem to implement them yet.

**Note**: I asked a similar question about PosgreSQL a few weeks ago.

A multi-table index could be very beneficial for some specific queries.

For reference, here are the *multi-table index* examples for Oracle and SQL Server:

**Oracle Example**

Oracle can create *bitmap join indexes*, as shown below:

```
create table dealer (
  id int primary key not null,
  city varchar2(20) not null
);

create table car (
  id int primary key not null,
  brand varchar2(20),
  price int,
  dealer_id int references dealer (id)
);

create bitmap index bix1 on car (d.city, c.brand)
from car c, dealer d
where d.id = c.dealer_id;

select avg(c.price)
from dealer d
join car c on c.dealer_id = d.id
where d.city = 'Chicago' and c.brand = 'Buick';
```

**SQL Server Example**

SQL Server can create *indexed views*:

```
create table dealer (
  id int primary key not null,
  city varchar(20) not null
);

create table car (
  id int primary key not null,
  brand varchar(20),
  price int,
  dealer_id int references dealer (id)
);

create view v with schemabinding as
select d.city, c.brand, c.price, c.dealer_id
from dbo.dealer d
join dbo.car c on c.dealer_id = d.id;

create unique clustered index uix1 on v (city, brand, price);

select avg(c.price)
from dealer d
join car c on c.dealer_id = d.id
where d.city = 'Chicago' and c.brand = 'Buick';
```

Is there anything similar in DB2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Db2 (for Linux, UNIX, and Windows) supports [indexes on tables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000919.html), i.e., you can only index a single table.

The table can be a MQT (materialized query table) which could be based on a view. This is different from indexing multiple tables directly.

Comment: What about MQT ?

Comment: added it to my answer

Comment: @data_henrik I like this option. It seems that using `REFRESH IMMEDIATE` may do all the hard word behind the scenes for me (of course at the cost of engine resources). Thanks. For the record, this article (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0708khatri/) explains the differences between Oracle and DB2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes like in SQL Server you can create indexes on views that span multiple tables.

Note -- you must set the view up in a special way (called materialized query table) for it to work.

Comment: MQT is a way to work round it - so I would anser the question as No but there is a workaround - that builds a single table first. So @data_henrik is absolutely right in his statement

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher -- ok, if the OP is claiming that SQL Server does this then it is the same (under the hood) -- note the key words `with schemabinding` in his example.  This is the SQL Server syntax for MQT

Comment: @Hogan From your answer it transpires that only Oracle has true multi-table indexes. DB2, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server go with the strategy of indexing materialized views; ...and their data refresh strategies are also different, in terms of opportunity and cost.

Comment: @TheImpaler -- your statement is valid.  However, I believe that DB2 gives significantly more options for refresh "strategies" than the others.  You can set materialized views to refresh on any change for example.